# How to compute the maximum of a floating point property of a Foldable via foldMap?

Tags: haskell, max, monoids, bounded-types, foldable

Say I have a map with measurable objects, and I'd like the maximum of their widths, defaulting to 0. The machinery of `Foldable` ([`foldMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldMap)) and `Semigroup` ([`Max`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Max)) seems perfect, except that I can't seem to introduce the arbitrary lower bound.

```
data Thing

width :: Thing -> Double

maxWidth :: Map k Thing -> Double
maxWidth things = getMax . foldMap (Max . width) $ things
```

This rightly complains about the missing `Bounded` instance for `Double`, since the `Monoid` instance of `Max a` uses `mempty = minBound`.

I see that the source for `Data.Foldable` uses a different definition of [`newtype Max`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/Data.Functor.Utils.html#Max) to implement [`maximum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#maximum). That variant would do nicely, but it seems to not be exported:

```
maxWidth things = fromMaybe 0 . getMax . foldMap (Max . Just . width) $ things
```

Comment: I think `max 0 . maximum . map width` would be more appropriate than trying to introduce a valid monoid.

Comment: As far as I understand, that would crash on an empty data structure.

Comment: What about `max 0 . Map.foldr max 0`? It's a bit redundant, but not too bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [**`Option`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Option) monoid to get a monoid instance for any `Semigroup`. `Option a` is just a newtype wrapper over `Maybe a`, but it's `Monoid` instance only requires `Semigroup a` rather than `Monoid a`. So we can use it with `Max`:

```
maximumMaybe :: (Ord a, Foldable t) => t a -> Maybe a
maximumMaybe = fmap getMax . getOption . foldMap (Option . Just . Max)
```

If you want a default value for the empty list case, you can use `fromMaybe`:

```
maximumWithDefault :: (Ord a, Foldable t) => a -> t a -> a 
maximumWithDefault d = fromMaybe d . maximumMaybe
```

Another option is to just use [**`maximumMay :: (Ord a, Foldable t) => t a -> Maybe a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-0.3.17/docs/Safe-Foldable.html#v:maximumMay) from the `safe` package.

If you are using `base-4.11.0` or higher, you no longer need the `Option a` type since the restriction on `Monoid (Maybe a)` has been lifted to `Semigroup a`. So as of `base-4.11.0`, which came with GHC 8.4.1, you can write:

```
maximumMaybe :: (Ord a, Foldable t) => t a -> Maybe a
maximumMaybe = fmap getMax . foldMap (Just . Max)
```